# Add onscreen keyboard in Flash with ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've made a MovieClip in the Flash Professional CC, with actionscript 3. I want to add a keyboard when anyone clicks on the "text input", without affecting other scenes. Note that I want to change the keyboard language whenever I need it.
Can any one help me?

Comment: You do need to create it yourself unless the code runs on a system that has a so-called "soft keyboard" built-in, that the Flash Player runtime is also aware of!

Answer (score 0):

When text entry is started, the user's OS will handle adding a soft keyboard on touch devices. I'm not sure of any way interface with the OS's soft keyboard to change languages and the like.

*Note: My solution only works if your SWF is being displayed on a web page.*

The only way to get the functionality you want would be to create your own soft keyboard. You could have a click event on the `TextField` call some JS via `ExternalInterface.call("someJS");` to show a div that's positioned over the swf. And in that div you could place your own swf that would contain the keyboard. When the user presses a key, you could use `ExternalInterface.addCallback("handleKeyPressed", _handleKeyPressed)` callbacks to pass that information back to the other SWF. This is a really complicated process but is feasible. But letting the OS handle the soft keyboard might be the better option.

[Check out the reference for ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)